# implementing datepicker with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm working on a UI application with asp.net mvc. I'm currently using bootstarp.
As i'm still learning about it, i'm confused about where to find the needed components. I used to work with kendo UI where all widgets and api are in the same place.
But now when I need some new functionality or widget (such as datepicker), I find that there are a lot of alternatives and plugins to be installed to choose from..
How should I choose, is there a bootstarp library that I can integrate and which will provide most of what I would need?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no package of widgets similar to jquery.ui. But some often used features like popovers and modals are already included in the [bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

We are using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) by Stefan Petre and Andrew Rowls, which you can install using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.Datepicker/).

```
$('#datePickerId').datepicker();
```